# Mouseleave not firing when creating an element below cursor in Webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

The following fiddle creates a 10px red square `div` when clicking on screen. This `div` has a `mouseleave` event attached to it to remove itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/fh4u44su/

If you click and move the cursor fast enough outside the `div`, the `mouseleave` event is not called (in Chrome and Safari, is called properly in Firefox).

It seems that if you create the element below the cursor and then move the cursor outside the element fast enough to not generate any `mousemove` events for the element, the `mouseleave` event is not triggered (so the element is not removed in the example).

Does anyone know if this is a documented bug, an intended behaviour for any reason, or if there is any workaround for it? By the way, it happens the same using `mouseout` event.

Comment: Which version of safari/chrome are you using?

Comment: Latest of Safari, Crome and Firefox, for Mac

Comment: can you change `e.target.remove();` to `$(e.target).remove();`? Let me know if it works.

Comment: That’s irrelevant, the `mouseleave` event is called and the red box is removed properly if a `mousemove` event is fired first (when moving the cursor slowly enough), but the `mouseleave` is not triggered otherwise.